# Using the differentiation of Neural Network in the loss function

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Instead of the difference in the neural network's output and the target value, I want to use the differentiation of the neural network in the MATLAB program.

For example:

```
input:        `(x, t)`
target:       `y:=u(x,t)`
output of NN: `N:=N(x,t)`
instead of `loss=sum(y(x_i, t_i) - N(x_i, t_i) , i=1,...,m)`,
I want to have `loss = sum(N_t(x_i, t_i) - N_xx(x_i, t_i), i=1,..,m)`
```

`N_t` is the derivative of the function `N(x,t)` related to `t`, and `N_xx` is the second derivative of `N(x,t)` related to `x`

How can I apply this change in MATLAB Neural Network Packages?

Comment: What are `N_t` and `N_xx`?

Comment: N_t is the derivative of the function N(x,t) related to t, and N_xx is the second derivative of N(x,t) related to x